# Firebase Crashlytics will not connect on secondary Xamarin Android app within the same project

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, crashlytics

Background:
I work on a proprietary business app, built with Xamarin Android, that my company creates and publishes two builds for. Due to how our contract system works, some of our clients were uncomfortable with certain app capabilities and permissions being enabled. What we have done for years is publish one version, then modify a few permissions, and publish another version of the application. Recently, we had an issue with a customers app crashing and none of our other error logging (run time logging we added ourselves via try catch blocks) was catching this. I did some looking and decided to add Firebase into the app and see if we could catch the exception. I was able to do this quickly with the first version of the app.

The Issue:
When attempting to build the second version, with reduced permissions, I needed to create another app profile within Firebase. I did so and added in the appropriate package name etc. This allowed me to generate a new Firebase json service file which I replaced the existing json with. The app simply will not connect with Firebase no matter what I try.

What I've tried:
1. I've rebuilt and started the app in both debug and release mode but it will not connect up with the Firebase service and show up in the console as having been connected.
2. I deleted the secondary Android profile and re-adding it, this didn't work either.
3. Forcing a crash using the `Crashlytics.Crashlytics.Instance.Crash();`
command also doesn't seem to make a difference.

What else should I try?

Edit:
Log is showing this.

```
[CrashlyticsCore] Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.3.25
[FA] App measurement is starting up, version: 11400
[FA] To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
[FA] To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
[FA]   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app 
[FA] Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance Id
[CrashlyticsInitProvider] CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
[FirebaseInitProvider] FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

Edit:
As my answer states below, I resolves this by simply creating a second Firebase project rather than trying to have two Android apps in the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to make this work exactly as intended, I was able to get a work around. I created a new Firebase Project and added the second version of the app there. This seemed to configure and work without an issue.